# i want to sort array of array basis on my child array index

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have on `NSMutableArray` , It is containing 20 `NSArray`. Now I want to sort may `NSMutableArray` basis on particular index

```
**Object 1**:(
Al Fresco - The Fruit Bar,
8 Patidar Society, Off. CG Road, Near TGB, Panchvati Cross Roads, Gulbai Tekra Rd, Panchavati Society, Gulbai Tekra, Amdavad,
CoQBegAAANnX8MekXEZA2KLckWQuZMaYQb01Q79iArH6Gf0jBHz_gmSimr4Zm-0Ns6WEmdkPwZJ_MBfOK-_r2T_P3myvH9itEss4FzUh6r0tH4h8zrw-jY9lgOSSuPKMd-EXiyuWjFlDnKG-VOS3fcy7AAvaIgujjiK23vYYWYn3R49gRw4mEhDdP7sGYp0fG0YuOzS-isx4GhTVU4rSVOta7GsZHvXxx4SuqFbWrA,
1.51,
23.023183,
72.555706
)
,

**Object 2**:(
Sarav Restaurant,
Jamnadas Chamber, Lal Darwaja, Lal Darwaja, Amdavad,
CoQBcgAAAE8z6_8pdBVzumQdsE8KskobotgcONp74KvE5cmygdMdFPv_S6doGmnrPM2six-KMBGPcKV24f4gKnTcj1ftfTYfEP0SrUZN6BCN6EVNBhZzeXUkdkjr3s6D3Rl0hAY3k2XdJdtNtTQ_tMlHvl0nS27fGb1yGVhn7VHCENsHaNS8EhAbD5pHmXCqfLD2dX8fi8uGGhRkOxv0xjIB5xDDBFp79gaD7SiElw,
0.94,
23.025021,
72.577415

)
```

[Ref Link](http://pastie.org/9198769)

Comment: Do you have any control over creating this array? if so, instead of having an array of arrays. You can have an array of dictionary.  I see that your child array has some details.. So you can put them in a dictionary. Sorting is easy.. You can do based on the key

Comment: you r right ,but now it is not possible for me,u have any other idea

Comment: Have you tried by 'NSPredicate'

Comment: i searched lot but not getting any idea!

Comment: sanjeet.. you can do it using sortUsingConparator: Check the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sortUsingComparator:`

```
[myMutableArray sortUsingComparator:^(id first, id second){
    id obj1 = [first objectAtIndex:yourIndex];
    id obj2 = [second objectAtIndex:yourIndex];

     return [obj1 compare:obj2];
}]
```

More info in the [NSMutableArray doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingComparator%3a)

Comment: This is probably the best solution. (voted) With sortUsingComparator, you write a block of code that compares pairs of objects and decides which should go first. In this case, the block compares objects in the child array, but you can do it any way you want.